# Problem with Reactjs nested routes on a vps with nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, routes, mern

I have a MERN application which work normally on localhost..
especially with nested routes.

For example when i access this url: https:localhost:3000/dashboard/users it works without any problem.
And i can get the correspondant view

But when i hosted the solution on a vps based on ubuntu 20.03 with nginx web server. I get a blank screen when i try to access the same url https:localhost:3000/dashboard/users

nginx host conf:

```
server {
    server_name soomy.tn www.soomy.tn;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/soomy.tn/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/soomy.tn/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    root /var/www/soomy/backend/build;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name soomy.tn www.soomy.tn;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


    # Add more location blocks for other nested routes if needed


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/soomy.tn/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/soomy.tn/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = soomy.tn) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name soomy.tn;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.soomy.tn) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name soomy.tn www.soomy.tn;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import ScrollUp from "./components/ScrollUp";
import FixedBar from "./components/FixedBar";
import CreditModal from "./components/CreditModal";
import { setCloseModalCredit } from "./redux/userSlice";
import "./scss/style.scss";
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getUser } from "./redux/userSlice";
import { getPurchase, getSelectedPurchase } from "./redux/packPurchaseSlice";
import { ProtectedRoute, AuthRoute, AdminRoute, ApprovedRoute,PhoneRoute } from "./AuthRoute";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { fetchUserParticipation } from "./redux/participationSlice";
import { handleClose, handleShow } from "./redux/dashboardSlice";
import SearchModal from "./components/SearchModal";
import Header from "./components/header/Header";
import 'antd/dist/reset.css';
import 'primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css';
import 'primereact/resources/primereact.min.css';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';

const loading = (
  <div className="pt-3 text-center">
    <div className="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
  </div>
);

// Containers
const DefaultLayout = React.lazy(() => import("./layout/DefaultLayout"));

// Pages
const Home = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/home/Home"));
const Categories = React.lazy(() =>
  import("./views/pages/auctions/Categories")
);
const Profile = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/profile/Profile"));
const ProfileUser = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/profile/User"));
const ProfileAuctions = React.lazy(() =>
  import("./views/pages/profile/Auctions")
);
const ProfileCommandes = React.lazy(() =>
  import("./views/pages/profile/Commandes")
);
const ProfileTransactions = React.lazy(() =>
  import("./views/pages/profile/Transactions")
);
const Faq = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/Instructions/Faq"));
const Auctions = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/auctions/Auctions"));
const SearchPage = React.lazy(() =>
  import("./views/pages/auctions/SearchPage")
);
const Validation = React.lazy(() =>
  import("./views/pages/checkout/Validation")
);
const Checkout = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/checkout/Checkout"));
const WindowPopup = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/windowPopup/WindowPopup"));
const Premium = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/auctions/Premium"));
const PremiumProduct = React.lazy(() =>
  import("./views/pages/products/PremiumProduct")
);
const Product = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/products/Product"));
const Finished = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/auctions/Finished"));
const Instructions = React.lazy(() =>
  import("./views/pages/Instructions/Instructions")
);
const Conditions = React.lazy(() =>
  import("./views/pages/Instructions/Conditions")
);
const Login = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/login/Login"));
const Register = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/register/Register"));
const Phone = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/register/Phone"));
const Reset = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/register/Reset"));
const Token = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/register/validate"));
const Mentions = React.lazy(() =>
  import("./views/pages/Instructions/Mentions")
);
const Page404 = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/page404/Page404"));
const Page500 = React.lazy(() => import("./views/pages/page500/Page500"));

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const { userInfo, showModal, montant } = user;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUser());
  }, []);
  
  const dashboard = useSelector((state) => state.dashboard);
  const { showSearch } = dashboard;

/*   useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      dispatch(fetchUserParticipation(userInfo._id));
    }
  }, [dispatch]); */

  return (
    <Router>
      <Header montant={montant} />
      <ScrollUp />
      <Suspense fallback={loading}>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/signin"
            name="Login Page"
            element={
              <AuthRoute>
                <Login />
              </AuthRoute>
            }
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/register"
            name="Register Page"
            element={<Register />}
          />
          <Route exact path="/phone" name="Register Page" element={<PhoneRoute><Phone /></PhoneRoute>} />
          <Route exact path="/validate" name="Validate Page" element={<Token />} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/reset"
            name="Reset Page"
            element={<Reset />}
          />
          <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" element={<Page404 />} />
          <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" element={<Page500 />} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/dashboard"
            name="Dashboard"
            element={
              <ApprovedRoute>
              <AdminRoute>
                <DefaultLayout />
              </AdminRoute>
              </ApprovedRoute>

            }
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/auction"
            name="Auction"
            element={<ApprovedRoute><Auctions /></ApprovedRoute>}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/search"
            name="SearchPage "
            element={<ApprovedRoute><SearchPage /></ApprovedRoute>}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/premium"
            name="Premium"
            element={<ApprovedRoute><Premium /></ApprovedRoute>}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/finished"
            name="Finished"
            element={<ApprovedRoute><Finished /></ApprovedRoute>}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/instructions"
            name="Instructions"
            element={<ApprovedRoute><Instructions /></ApprovedRoute>}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/conditions"
            name="Conditions"
            element={<ApprovedRoute><Conditions /></ApprovedRoute>}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/mentions"
            name="Mentions"
            element={<ApprovedRoute><Mentions /></ApprovedRoute>}
          ></Route>
          <Route exact path="/faq" name="Faq" element={<Faq />}></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/product/:id"
            name="Product"
            element={<ApprovedRoute><Product /></ApprovedRoute>}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/premiumproduct/:id"
            name="PremiumProduct"
            element={<ApprovedRoute><PremiumProduct /></ApprovedRoute>}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/category/:id"
            name="Categories"
            element={<ApprovedRoute><Categories /></ApprovedRoute>}
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/profile"
            name="Profile"
            element={
              <ApprovedRoute>
              <ProtectedRoute>
                <Profile />
              </ProtectedRoute>
              </ApprovedRoute>
            }
          >
            <Route
              exact
              index
              name="ProfileUser"
              element={<ProfileUser />}
            ></Route>
            <Route
              exact
              path="auctions"
              name="ProfileAuctions "
              element={<ProfileAuctions />}
            ></Route>
            <Route
              exact
              path="commandes"
              name="ProfileCommandes"
              element={<ProfileCommandes />}
            ></Route>
            <Route
              exact
              path="transactions"
              name="ProfileTransactions"
              element={<ProfileTransactions />}
            ></Route>
          </Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/validation/:id"
            name="Validation"
            element={
              <ApprovedRoute>
              <ProtectedRoute>
                <Validation />
              </ProtectedRoute>
              </ApprovedRoute>
            }
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/checkout/:id"
            name="Checkout"
            element={
              <ApprovedRoute>
              <ProtectedRoute>
                <Checkout />
              </ProtectedRoute>
              </ApprovedRoute>
            }
          ></Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/WindowPopup"
            name="WindowPopup"
            element={<WindowPopup />}
          ></Route>
          <Route index path="*" name="Home" element={<ApprovedRoute><Home /></ApprovedRoute>}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
      <ToastContainer />

      <FixedBar />
      <SearchModal show={showSearch} onHide={() => dispatch(handleClose())} />
      {userInfo ? <CreditModal show={showModal} montant={montant} /> : null}
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

.env

```
PORT = 5000
BASE_URL = "https://soomy.tn"
MONGO_URI = "mongodb+srv://soomytn:diwblzXojR59ej2X@soomy.hyo3vo1.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "soomy2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon backend/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cron": "^2.1.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.2",
    "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.7.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.8",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "primereact": "^9.4.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.2",
    "twilio": "^3.81.0",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.13"
  }
}
```

Also i am building the app on frontend. and to increase its performance by copying the build in backend.
I really tried many different tuto but without getting any solution. Perhaps it is a missing or an incorrect config. I need your help!

Comment: how did you serve the reactjs build file, did you use node js to serve react js application?

Comment: You have 2 server blocks listening for `server_name soomy.tn www.soomy.tn;` and port `443` and both on the root directory `/`. What is the second server block for? Seems unneeded to me, maybe just uncomment it. Overall I think this behavior is a result from the conflict between these 2 blocks.

Comment: @JohnGeorge exactly and i use pm2 to auto run server

Comment: @Geilmaker i commented the second server section but still have the same issue. /dashboard/dashboard should load a dashboard view. instead of that i get return to the home page with the same end point.

Comment: Have you tried accessing your application directly on the port 5000? That would be much helpful to determine wether its nginx or application error. In this case it sounds like application error to me.

Comment: @Geilmaker and when i refresh the same url "/dashboard/dashboard/ i get a blank page "you must turn on javascript"

Comment: @Hityou05 can you share the server code

Answer (score 0):

Changing homepage attribute in package.json from "."to "" ("homepage"="") was the solution.

Comment: It would be better to support your answer with an example code or show the changed part in your answer.